# What build will users receive if they received a new build during a staged rollout, and then reinstall after a staged rollout is halted?

Tags: android, google-play

Situation is as follows:

1. Upload new build to playstore, release as staged rollout to x%.
2. User Y updates to latest build.
3. Staged rollout halted due to some issue.
4. User Y uninstalls and reinstalls application.

Does User Y have the pre-staged rollout build when they reinstall, or the new build?